# Why won't Omnikey 5325 smartcard reader recognize my card?

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, winscard

I purchased a smartcard reader (OMNIKEY 5325 CL USB Prox) and installed all the drivers but I it won't read my card (1386 ISOProx II Card).  The diagnostic tool doesn't seem to recognize it, and calling SCardTransmit returns ERROR_GEN_FAILURE.  The tool says the resource manager is started and running but it doesn't say a version number for scardsvr.dll.  Just N/A.  My card definitely works, but I'm totally stumped on this.  Tried uninstalling all the drivers and everything.  Running windows 7.  Any ideas?

[Screenshots of diagnostic tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWOWm.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for anybody that comes across this with a similar problem.  For 125kHz Prox cards, the ATR contains the facility code and customer identifier code.  There are no SCardTransmit calls.

http://www.planc.biz/pdf/CM5125_RegKey.pdf

The trick is setting up the registry values to match what format your card uses.  Mine did not work with the formats specified there, but we were able to get it working by using the "customer defined" option and putting in our own format similar to H10304 using the StartBit and BitLength values.  Wish there was easier documentation/apis for smartcards, but at least it works!